# Increase width by 100px on each click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Straight to the point: When I click the button, **I want the width of the box to increase by 100px, on each click**. Could someone help me to achieve this?

Currently the width of the box goes to 400px when clicking the button, but I want to increase the width by 100px on each click to the button.

You can find the code below.

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    content.style.width = "400px";
});
```

```css
#content {
    width: 300px; height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#btn {
    width: 100px; height: 50px;
    background: grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting width 400px every time. You need to take the width and then add 100 more px to the existing width. 
for ex:

```
var width1 = content.offsetWidth 
content.style.width= (width1+100)+"px";
```

Please go through below snippet.

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
var width1 = content.offsetWidth
content.style.width= (width1+100)+"px";
});
```

```css
#content {
width: 300px; height: 100px;
background: lightblue;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#btn {
width: 100px; height: 50px;
background: grey;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `width` variable to save and increment the value:

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var width = 400;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  width += 100;
  content.style.width = width + "px";
});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get with from content, and reuse it

```
content.style.width = content.offsetWidth + 100 + "px";
```

Your demo below

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.style.width = content.offsetWidth + 100 + "px";
});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Comment: Very straightforward! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a variable that increases every time that you click the button, and set that as the width. The below code it the final result. No changes were made to your HTML or CSS, just to your JavaScript. I created a variable called add and it starts at 300, and then every time that the button gets clicked, add gets 100 added to itself, and then it gets displayed.

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content"), btn = document.getElementById("btn"), add = 300;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
add+=100;
content.style.width = add.toString()+"px";
});
```

```css
#content {
width: 300px; height: 100px;
background: lightblue;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#btn {
width: 100px; height: 50px;
background: grey;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
content.style.width = (content.offsetWidth) + 100 + "px";
```

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
 content.style.width = (content.offsetWidth) + 100 + "px";
});
```

```css
#content {
width: 300px; height: 100px;
background: lightblue;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#btn {
width: 100px; height: 50px;
background: grey;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `offsetWidth` instead of content.style.width in click function body

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    content.style.width = (content.offsetWidth+100)+'px'
});
```